# Access ref prop from MapView component for use by outside function

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-maps

Is there a way to access the ref property from MapView component from an outside function?

Basically, I have:

1. A main component which has a render method that will call `(<MyMap />)`
2. `<MyMap />` is an exported function with the MapView Component.  Inside the MapView component, I make a reference `(ref=map=>(mapRef=map)` and want to pass that reference to the function that generates my markers `(<PinData />`.
3. In `<PinData />`, I want to use the onPress event for
   the marker to zoom in and move to the marker using the
   MapView.animateToRegion method.

**I keep getting the undefined is not an object (evaluating 'mapRef.animateToRegion').**

Do I have to create component classes (instead of using exported functions) for the map reference to work in order to render the MapView and Markers components?

Ex:
Main Class component:

```
render(){
     return(
          <View>
             <MyMap region={this.state.region} 
                    pinData={this.state.pinsData} 
                    myPins={this.state.myPins}
                    mapRef={this._mapRef} />
          </View>
)}
```

MyMap function renders my MapView component.

```
export const MyMap= ({ region, pinsData, myPins}) => {

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        ref={map => (mapRef = map)}
        style={styles.userMap}
        region={region}
      >
        <PinData pinsData={pinsData} myPins={myPins} />
      </MapView>
    </View>
  );
```

PinData Function which is used to generate markers on my map.

```
export const PinData = ({ pinsData, myPins, mapRef }) => {
  return pinsData.map((pin, index) => (
    <Marker
      key={index}
      ref={ref => (markers[index] = ref)}
      coordinate={{
        longitude: pin.coordinates.lng,
        latitude: pin.coordinates.lat
      }}
      onPress={focusMarker(mapRef, pin, index)}
    />
  ));
};
```

onPress function which would zoom into one of the pins using the animateToRegion method associated with the MapView object.

```
focusMarker = (mapRef, location, index) => {
  mapRef.animateToRegion({
    latitude: location.coordinates.lat,
    longitude: location.coordinates.lng,
    latitudeDelta: 0.005,
    longitudeDelta: 0.005
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass an `onPress` prop to `PinData`

```
export const MyMap= ({ region, pinsData, myPins}) => {
    const mapRef = useRef();

  focusMarker = (location) => {
    mapRef.current.animateToRegion({
      latitude: location.coordinates.lat,
      longitude: location.coordinates.lng,
      latitudeDelta: 0.005,
      longitudeDelta: 0.005
    });
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        ref={mapRef}
        style={styles.userMap}
        region={region}
      >
        <PinData pinsData={pinsData} myPins={myPins} onPress={focusMarker}/>
      </MapView>
   </View>
);

}

export const PinData = ({ pinsData, myPins, onPress }) => {
  return pinsData.map((pin, index) => (
    <Marker
      key={index}
      ref={ref => (markers[index] = ref)}
      coordinate={{
        longitude: pin.coordinates.lng,
        latitude: pin.coordinates.lat
      }}
      onPress={() => onPress(pin)}
    />
  ));
};
```

Comment: This works perfectly.  Quick question, just so I understand the logic of how this works.  You create a ref to the MapView component by calling useRef().   How does the onPress part work?  You reference a prop called onPress and link it to the focusMarker function.  Then, in the PinData function, you call an anonymous function for onPress Marker prop which points to onPress(that takes in pin) as a parameter.  How does this onPress work?  How does the focusMarker reference the pin in the PinData function?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, thanks to Tuan's answer.  The code above works.  What I wasnt understanding before is how the onPress worked.  Basically, from my understanding, the logic is as follows:

Within the MyMap function, we define the focusMarker function.

Then create a prop within the  called onPress and set it equal to the focusMarker function.

In the PinData function, we now take this prop(onPress) in as a parameter and set the onPress prop in the Marker component to an anonymous function which will execute the focusMarker function with a parameter of pin.  In this function, onPress which is passed in as a parameter for the exported function is actually the focusMarker function itself and we are calling it with a parameter of pin.  Hope that makes sense to anyone who can utilize this.  Thanks again Tuan.  Appreciate it.  I was stumped on this for a while.